# Why does the HTML video tag have a default size and can it be controlled?

Tags: html, video

I was having an issue with an HTML5 video that let me to find that `video` tag elements have a default size of 300x150, even when no source or size is supplied. Here is a short snippet showing the behaviour.

```
<video style="background-color: red;">
</video>
<div style="background-color: blue;">
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qmtfsef7/)

I included the `div`tag with the same CSS, and it is set to 0px by 0px default. I have tested this in Firefox and Chrome. If one axis `video` element's dimension is changed in the Chrome debugger, the other axis is changed to maintain a 2-1 proportion (this also holds true adding a style setting width: 100%).

Is this behaviour documented anywhere? I wasn't able to find anything on why it occurs and whether it can be controlled. I want to set the default aspect ratio of the video to avoid the element from rescaling when it has neither a source or a poster. I've noticed this occuring during for a single frame after the video is loaded: the poster is hidden but the video content is not yet displayed, resulting in the video rescaling to the default size. I avoid the video from turning white by setting the background-image to match the poster, but because the aspect ratio changes to 2-1 there is a noticeable "blink" during the first frame. Being able to set the default aspect ratio to 16-9 would correct this issue.

Comment: As of my understanding there is no default size for video tag, it may be based on your video. And moreover you can control it. Refer this url https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try either inline styling or css from stylesheet

```
<video src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls poster="video.png" id="styled_video" muted preload="metadata" loop>
```

Here's a link for reference

http://ronallo.com/blog/styling-html5-video-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<video width="300" height="200" controls><source src="path" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it right there in the video tag:

```
<video width="250" height="250" style="background-color: red;">
</video>
<div style="background-color: blue;">
</div>
```